# php file access

Tags: php

I need some help with php.

So my external php file(track2.php) is in /wp-content/plugins/buzzr_tracking.

now inside this track2.php i want to access a text file located inside the folder */wp-content/trackclicks*

**But before i access it i want to check its presence using "file_exists"**.

so any ideas what **directory structure i should apply while using the function file_exists**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```
file_get_contents("../../trackclicks/my_file.txt")
```

That should get you the contents of the file.

Comment: what if i am using the function "file_exists".  then what syntax?

Comment: @Ayusha Same thing. Just change the function.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a text file you want to access just use fopen with full path to file.

Make sure you have file permissions to open the file as the user executing php (not the user you login as) because typically php is not executed by your own user account but rather apache or something.

```
//code in track2.php 
$handle = fopen("/wp-content/trackclicks/<fileName>", "r");
```

Comment: actually i am only using the function "file_exists" on the text file. So for that function also the same syntax?